How to install steps on a steep hillside
I need to install steps on his steep hillside to access the front yard or the backyard. The clay soil is very compacted. It has been covered in pine straw for several gears. Steps cannot be wider than 14 inches. The length of this project is about 15 feet. It’s short, but it’s steep. I need something not complicated.

How steep is the ground?

You might check if you locale has requirements for steps, such as dimensions, maximum rise, handrails... Though the steps might be only for personal use, if someone were hurt on them, insurance might reject payment. Yes, that does complicate what could have been a simple project. sigh

If it's just for your own use and you're reasonably sure-footed, you might set a straight ladder down on the slope and call it a day. (This is a technique I use on steep and/or snow-covered roofs.) If constructing actual steps is a must, could you get approximate measurements of rise and run to help us understand just how steep?
